# Simulation threads conflict even when started by different processes

Tags: java, process, batch-file, threadpool

I have a code base that deals with simulation of certain data. It involves lot of threads and lot of complications.

I just tried using that base as jar and ran multiple simulations through a batch file like below.

```
start java-cp base.jar; Sim1.java
start java-cp base.jar; Sim2.java
start java-cp base.jar; Sim3.java
```

I get interrupted exceptions since the code base contain simulation code that has lot of holds and waits.

I want to know whether using the same jar creates the conflict. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Wait/notify does not cross JVM boundries.

Comment: Maybe they are locking on some file that they generate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a lock on a file. I was trying to use the same file in multiple process. 
Thanks Hiro2k.